# multiprocessing result to list

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to let my results of the multiprocessing to 2 lists how could I do that. I tried below but only get the last one list.

```
def multiply(x, y):
  return x * x, x * y

#use wrap
def multiply_wrapper(args):
  return multiply(*args)

#use wrap
if __name__ == "__main__":
  list_x = []
  list_y = []

  p = Pool(4)
  values = [(x, y) for x in range(4) for y in range(4)]
  results = p.map(multiply_wrapper, values)
  
  list_x.append(results[0][0])
  list_y.append(results[0][1])

  print(list_x)
  print(list_y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with small changes and `results` looks ok.

Did you perhaps expect the multiprocessing to leave the data separated according to which worker processed the chunk of data?  Fortunately, it joins the data for us.

The following inspired from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) and your original question.  Also don't forget to release resources as the garbage collector will not do this for you.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import pprint

def multiply(x, y):
  return x * x, x * y

#use wrap
def multiply_wrapper(args):
  return multiply(*args)

#use wrap
if __name__ == "__main__":
  p = Pool(4)
  values = [(x, y) for x in range(4) for y in range(4)]
  results = p.map(multiply_wrapper, values)
  p.close()
  p.join()
  pprint.pprint(results)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0),
 (0, 0),
 (0, 0),
 (0, 0),
 (1, 0),
 (1, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (4, 0),
 (4, 2),
 (4, 4),
 (4, 6),
 (9, 0),
 (9, 3),
 (9, 6),
 (9, 9)]
```

---

*Replying to comments:*

To obtain 2 lists from the output of `Pool.map`, we can unzip the result.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(4)
    values = [(x, y) for x in range(4) for y in range(4)]
    results = p.map(multiply_wrapper, values)
    p.close()
    p.join()

    list_x = [x[0] for x in results]
    list_y = [x[1] for x in results]
    pprint.pprint(list_x)
    pprint.pprint(list_y)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4, 6, 0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I want to do is separate them to two lists.

Comment: @Z.L Can you give more context on what problem you are trying to solve?  Are you facing an issue with multiprocessing (since that is in the title)?

Comment: If you are constrained to use `Pool.map()`, then realize its return result is a single `list`.  If you are looking to obtain 2 `list`s from this, then you can do so manually.  I'll update answer with an example of this.

Comment: Thank you ,your second solution actually run! That's very helpful. Thank you

Comment: That's great to hear.  If you found this useful, kindly accept as answer.  Thank you.